# Where are the command-line options to perl documented?

Tags: perl, documentation

On StackExchange I came across a command that looked like this:

```
perl -pe ...
```

Curious what the `-pe` options meant, I did `man perl`.  This is the synopsis of that man page:

```
perl [ -sTtuUWX ]      [ -hv ] [ -V[:configvar] ]      [ -cw ] [ -d[t][:debugger] ] [ -D[number/list] ]      [ -pna ] [ -Fpattern ] [ -l[octal] ] [ -0[octal/hexadecimal] ]
        [ -Idir ] [ -m[-]module ] [ -M[-]'module...' ] [ -f ]      [ -C [number/list] ]      [ -S ]      [ -x[dir] ]      [ -i[extension] ]
        [ [-e|-E] 'command' ] [ -- ] [ programfile ] [ argument ]...
```

However, the man page does not explain what any of the options `sTtuUWXhvcwpnafS` do.  Instead it refers you to `perldoc`.  However, I can't seem to find any reference to the actual command line arguments in `perldoc`.  Where are they actually documented?  Is there some secret linux documentation information retrieval method I am unaware of here?

<sup>On a side note/rant, is the fact that I can't find this information an indication of a failing in the perl documentation?  I am happy to read the documentation rather than just ask questions online, but I swear finding my answer in the documentation can be near impossible at times! Graarh! /rant</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perlrun` is the manpage you're looking for:

```
man perlrun
```

Comment: Egh.  How was I supposed to know that?!

Comment: `man perl` has references to specific versions of perl at the end (the 'see also' section, usually overlooked). Following them (e.g. `man perl5.12`) gives you all the manual pages you can think of.

Comment: `man perl` primarily lists all of the other perl man pages, including `perlrun             Perl execution and options`

Comment: [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)'s online copy has hyperlinks and nicer formatting. Just to know that option too.

Comment: Also note that not all distros install the complete perl manpages by default, so you might have to do, for example on Ubuntu, `sudo apt install perl-doc`.

Answer (score 1):

`perl -h` is useful

- `-e program`:        one line of program (several `-e`'s allowed, omit programfile)
- `-p`:                assume loop like `-n` but print line also, like `sed`